# How to set ACL permissions using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unix, ios9, acl

What is the best way to do:

```
chmod -R -N <path>
```

Using Obj-C?

I tried playing with PosixPermissions unsuccessfully. For an example:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFilePosixPermissions: @493} ofItemAtPath:fullPath error:nil];
```

Is useless.

Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: When you say 'is useless': what happens as a result of that code? What do you get back if you actually allow it to report an error instead of `error:nil`ing and hoping for the best?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:

Comment: @Tommy I mean the permissions are set to 493 successfully, but the ACL permissions don't change.